# Why will my Seagate drive only boot off its USB 3.0 interface and not its Thunderbolt interface?

Tags: macos, boot, usb, thunderbolt

*Jump to the bottom to see a refinement to this question.*

I have a Seagate Backup Plus for Mac 3-Terabyte drive.  I use it with both OSX 10.9.1 Time Machine hourly and Carbon Copy Cloner (CCC) nightly.  I can boot off this external drive from its USB 3.0 interface a la the CCC backup image.  *I cannot boot off the same image via its Thunderbolt interface.*  Seagate says that its not a Thunderbolt requirement to be able to boot - **I beg to differ**.

*Note:  The box also says that no reformatting is required (see picture at [Apple Discussions Forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5511586)), however, it needed to be reformatted to work with Mavericks.*  Check out: [Why would re-formatting an external disk drive stop random drive disconnects in OSX Mavericks?](https://superuser.com/questions/699948/why-would-re-formatting-an-external-disk-drive-stop-random-drive-disconnects-in)

A related issue is that Apple's Time Machine will not see this drive when it is connected through its Thunderbolt interface - see the discussion before the refinement to this question at the bottom of this question's text.

I was just about to reference [my post on the Apple Discussion Forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5511586), when I noticed that an answer, *not a good answer*, but an answer none-the-less has been posted concerning this very question, but there is still some hope for this question - *jump to the bottom*.

*Besides, if someone else on *this website* can save the money that me and at least one other person wasted, then this post would have been worth it, no?*

According to a post at the Apple discussion forum, someone lays fault on the the adapter as follows:

Here is response by Seagate after I contacted them about this problem:

> The reason the Thunderbolt adapter is not allowing the restore
>   function to be seen is due to the driver converting the 512k sector to
>   4k sector. The driver is already built into USB 3.0 so my
>   recommendation would be to use the USB 3.0 to restore the Time Machine
>   backup.
>
> When you are restoring from the Thunderbolt adapter the driver is
>   absent . The conversion is not happening so the drive is not showing
>   up. Unfortunately, I cannot give a time frame on when or if this will
>   be corrected. The issue is definitely related to the drivers in the
>   adapter itself though.

Note that when I upgraded from Mountain Lion to Mavericks, I had a problem with this drive working on both the USB 3.0 or Thunderbolt interfaces at all, and I ended up removing a kext file out of /System/Library/Extensions to get it to work after the OS upgrade - this may or may not have anything to do with the problem - regardless, this particular drive does not boot from the Thunderbolt interface in either Mountain Lion or Mavericks:

[image: Error message]

My follow-on question

*Does someone have a way to patch the driver for the Thunderbolt interface to allow it to do the 512k to 4k conversion and get Thunderbolt support from Time Machine restoration and/or just being able to boot off the Thunderbolt interface?*

Comment: Sounds like you are at the mercy of Seagate to provide an updated driver to Apple ( or how ever they wish to publish this driver to their customers ).

Comment: Sounds like I could safely keep the reputation points I offer for a bounty for the resolution of this?  ;-)  However, I wonder if it would be possible to reformat the drive with 4k instead of 512k sectors?  But that sounds like a lot of waiting on data to transfer to 1) see if the solution works, & to 2) find out that the performance of the unit is terrible with 4k sector sizes effectually rendering it a solution that doesn't work - see 1).  Seagate did say right on the box that no formatting would be involved - maybe I need to hold them to this statement & get my money back or force a driver?

Comment: I think the chances of somebody having a fixed driver is unlikely given that Seagate is aware of the problem and an ETA is not known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proposing and accepting answer as per a comment.  It's on Seagate, and it may never get resolved.  Case close.